# Delete a listbox item in OnDraw?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a listbox and add items to it, items are address of files, items are added after some processes and they are inserted like this:

```
Listbox_Browser.Items := myItems;
```

so as im not adding them one by one i cant check them during inserting ti listbox, i tried to check them in OnDraw and used a code like this:

```
  Try
    FileOpenandP(Listbox_Browser.Items[Index]);
  Except
    ListBox_Browser.Items.Delete(Index);
  End;
```

but i got the error "List index out of bounds", what is the solution?

Comment: As a golden rule of thumb: a presenting control only asks for data to present, it will never ask why. if it does, you get something wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `OnDrawItem` event is for **drawing only**.  You are not supposed to be **managing** your list inside that event, only drawing its current items as needed.

Instead of assiging the whole list at one time, you **should** be checking the files first, **then** assign the remaining list to the ListBox, eg:

```
I := 0;
while I < myItems.Count do
begin
  try
    FileOpenandP(myItems[I]);
    Inc(I);
  except
    myItems.Delete(I);
  end;
end;
ListBox_Browser.Items := myItems;
```

If you don't want `myItems` altered, use a separate list instead:

```
tmpItems := TStringList.Create;
try
  tmpItems.Assign(myItems);
  I := 0;
  while I < tmpItems.Count do
  begin
    try
      FileOpenandP(tmpItems[I]);
      Inc(I);
    except
      tmpItems.Delete(I);
    end;
  end;
  ListBox_Browser.Items := tmpItems;
finally
  tmpItems.Free;
end;
```

Or:

```
ListBox_Browser.Items := myItems;
I := 0;
while I < ListBox_Browser.Items.Count do
begin
  try
    FileOpenandP(ListBox_Browser.Items[I]);
    Inc(I);
  except
    ListBox_Browser.Items.Delete(I);
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
ListBox_Browser.Items.BeginUpdate;
try
  ListBox_Browser.Items.Clear;
  I := 0;
  for I := 0 to myItems.Count-1 do
  begin
    try
      FileOpenandP(myItems[I]);
    except
      Continue;
    end;
    ListBox_Browser.Items.Add(myItems[I]);
  end;
finally
  ListBox_Browser.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```